# What is a word for someone who enjoys keeping fish as a hobby?

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english

I am looking for a word for someone who enjoys keeping fish at their home. They have a pond with a large number of Koi Carp, as well as a room with fish tanks containing a variety of fish. This is for pleasure rather than profit. Is there a noun for this kind of **fish hobbyist**?

Comment: I'd call him a Piscopalean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This hobby is called [fishkeeping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fishkeeping) and the corresponding noun for the hobbyist is *fishkeeper*.

---

A less commonly used alternative is *aquarist*:

> a person who keeps or maintains an aquarium

<sub>(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aquarist))</sub>

though it's probably less appropriate if you want to focus on their (garden) fish ponds.